# How to tell date in German?

Tags: numbers, declension, adjective-ending, time

Is 14th of February *vierzehnte zweite* or *vierzehnten zweiten*?

With the usage of the name of the month, is it *vierzehnten Februar* or *vierzehnte Februar*?

**Why is there an *-n* sometimes and sometimes it isn't?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It can be **nominative**:

> Heute ist **der vierzehnte Februar**.

Or **dative**:

> **Am vierzehnten Februar** war ich in Urlaub (already mentioned by Benedikt Brünner)

Or **accusative**:

> [Captain's logbook]: 32° 12' W 14° 34' S, wir schreiben **den vierzehnten Februar**.

Or **genitive**:

> Am Morgen **des vierzehnten Februars** sammelten wir uns zur Abreise.

So you see, all four cases can and do occur. And there are more prepositions besides *am* that can go with a date. Note the [terminal **-s** in *Februars* for the genitive](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/post-an-den-zwiebelfisch-klarer-fall-von-trabbis-a-372437.html)*, note the terminal **-n** in the adjective *vierzehnten* for dative, accusative and genitive.

Finally, another **nominative** form without an article is

> **Vierzehnter Februar**.

<sub>*However: Not marking the genitive case of the month with a terminal 's' is becoming increasingly popular; at present, it is a matter of subjective choice.</sub>

Comment: I disagree with the claim that the genitive forms such as "Februars" or "Septembers" are still current in dates. This must have sounded antiquated even a hundred years ago. To judge from the graphs on Google's n-gram viewer for pairs such as "des 1. Februar,des 1. Februars", the switch seems to have happened around the middle of the 19th century.

Answer (score 6):

The words are adjectives (literally, *fourteenth second*) in masculine gender, because *Tag* and *Monat* are masculine, and follow the [usual rules for adjective declension](http://www.deutschonline.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm). Therefore, it is:

> vierzehnter zweiter
>   der vierzehnte zweite
>   am vierzehnten zweiten
>   der Abend des vierzehnten zweiten
>   etc.

In many cases, it is more common to use the name of the month instead:

> am vierzehnten Februar

Still, the same declension rules apply to the day.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer:

> Am vierzehnten Februar

(I'm from Austria)

Comment: @downvoters: please note that this was the first answer posted here, and it is a valid answer (even though  admittedly we do have better ones in the meantime). Related: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/422/does-careless-voting-or-non-voting-damage-this-site

Comment: @Takkat: In my opinion, it doesn’t answer the (main point of the) question, which was _why_ there are different forms (with and without _-n_) in the wild. It might even mislead a reader into believing that _vierzehnten_ is always right.

Comment: yeah, sure it's not a **good** answer, because its incomplete but its not wrong either. 3(!) downvotes **without further explanation** is bad style. This should not happen to a new user who only came here today to contribute. We should put more effort in helping people how to give good answers - my 2 ct.

Comment: Well, it has also received two upvotes … Still a net reputation gain of at least 14.

Comment: Sometimes questions can be answered with 1 short sentence like this one, and it was the first reply the question received, means the topic has finished. And I don't understand why an avalanche of overkill must follow, crowned by downvoting the first answer.

Comment: +1 just to agree with most of you

Comment: Man bewertet nicht, ob eine Antwort die erste ist oder nicht sondern ihre Qualität. Der Zeitpunkt ist ohnehin objektiv ablesbar. Ist ein Teilnehmer sehr umtriebig ist auch später nur mühsam nachvollziehbar dass die Antwort die erste der Person war, und womöglich daher nachsichtig bewertet wurde, und die hohe Bewertung fehlleitend. Außerdem ist der Zusatz zur Herkunkft in der Antwort völlig sinnlos.